# Purpose of asynchronous task queue

Tags: asynchronous, celery

i'm new to web development, so bear with. I just came across [Celery, an asynchronous task queue](http://celeryproject.org/).  After reading the documentation, what i get that `celery` is adding a delay to a code and then run its process in background. I don't really get it, i thought it's just like a normal AJAX, if yes, what's the advantage using this so-called `asynchronous task queue`, if not, what's the difference between a normal ajax call and async task queue. Would be good if you guys give me some real world example. Thanks.